# Database access gives a java.null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, oop, android-sqlite

I created my first android app. Everything works except for one problem. When I open the database in my app. In my oncreate activity it runs fine. But when I use the same code to retrieve values in a method, my application crashes and gives a `java.null pointer exception`.

So my question is that, is there another way of opening database in a method or I am doing something wrong. Here is my code.

Here my method giving java.null pointer exception.

```
public class SendGlass extends Activity{

  static String replay;

   public void sms (String phone,String Sms )
   {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

        String phoneNo = phone;
        String sms = Sms;
        String api = "You Entered one";
        String api2 = "You Entered two";
        String api3 = "Nothing great";
        String rep = sms.replace(phoneNo+" :", "");

        SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("ComDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT REPLAYS FROM Rtm WHERE ID = 1", null);

        while(c.moveToNext())
        {
            replay = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("REPLAYS"));

            if(rep.equals("1"))
            {
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, replay, null, null);
            }
            if(rep.equals("2"))
            {
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, replay, null, null);
            }
            if(rep.equals("3"))
            {
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, replay, null, null);
            }
            if(rep.equals("4"))
            {
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, replay, null, null);
            }
            if(rep.equals("5"))
            {
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, replay, null, null);
            }
            if(rep.equals("6"))
            {
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, replay, null, null);
            }
            if(rep.equals("7"))
            {
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, replay, null, null);
            }
            if(rep.equals("8"))
            {
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, replay, null, null);
            }
       }
 }
```

I am giving parameter to this code by

```
     class obj = new Class();
     obj.sms (value,value )
```

Comment: where do you get the exception. post the logcat also

Comment: which line did you get null pointer exception?

Comment: you also could use a switch case for the "rep" variable.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

c.moveToFirst ():

do{
      your code ////

}
while(c.moveToNext)